# Property validation

Tags: c#, .net, validation, reflection

I require that the `Feature` set of my `Licence` to have a non-empty intersection with a set of features that the module I am loading contains.  I expect other lists in my License to form similar requirements, and I wish to be able to specify as much information as possible on the license object, i.e. I do not wish to need to update the Validator if the contents of the License object changes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Testing
{
    public class License
    {
        [CollectionIntersects]
        public List<string> Features { get; set; }       
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public abstract class LicenseValidator:Attribute
    {
        public abstract bool isValid(object context, object obj, PropertyInfo property);
    }

    public class Validator
    {
        public static bool isValid(object context, object obj)
        {
            bool valid = true;
            Type objType = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] props = objType.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
            {
                foreach (LicenseValidator validator in prop.GetCustomAttributes<LicenseValidator>())
                {
                    valid=valid&&validator.isValid(context, obj, prop);
                }
            }
            return valid;
        }
    }

    public class CollectionIntersects: LicenseValidator
    {
        public CollectionIntersects()
        {
        }

        public override bool isValid(object context, object obj, PropertyInfo property)
        {
            Type collectionType = property.PropertyType;
            Object contextvalue = property.GetValue(context);
            Object objectvalue = property.GetValue(obj);

            //Casting code lifted from
            //http://stackoverflow.com/a/31380177/1986513.
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
            dynamic contextvalueenum =
                Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(param, collectionType), param).Compile().DynamicInvoke(contextvalue);
            dynamic licencevalueenum =
                Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(param, collectionType), param).Compile().DynamicInvoke(objectvalue);

            return ((IEnumerable<object>)Enumerable.Intersect(contextvalueenum, licencevalueenum)).Any();
        }

    }

}
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish this? Also, how sensitive is it to localization and collation issues considering that the license might be written in a different locale than the reference context object?

Answer (score 1):

Self answer, one nights sleep later.

A simpler solution can be made by making the arguments of the function dynamic.  The isValid method can then be written as;

```
    public override bool isValid(dynamic context, dynamic obj, PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<object>)Enumerable.Intersect(property.GetValue(context), property.GetValue(obj))).Any();
    }
```